# How to modify lines in file using SED

Tags: sed

I have a file in which each line starts with `test.x:x`.

I want to delete `.x:x` from each line using sed. I want to know how can I do that?

I tried below but it deletes the whole line:

```
sed '/.x:x/d' tt.txt
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Take a look at sed's `s` command.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. here's what i wanted.

I had a file which contains lines as below.

```
harpreet$ cat ttt.txt 
test1.set:set
test2.set:set
test3.set:set
test4.set:set
test5.set:set
```

and I wanted to print only test on the console using sed as below.

```
harpreet$ sed 's/.set:set//' ttt.txt
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
harpreet$$
```

Comment: You could edit your original post with this new info.  This solution will also change `test1xset:set` to `test1`, since you did not escape the dot and it will be interpreted as any character, so a better solution would be `sed 's/\.set:set//'`. And if what you like to remove are at the end of the line, you could anchor it like this `sed 's/\.set:set$//'`